# SSH authorization in Ansible between local and remote host

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys, openssh, lxc

I have a Vagrant box with centos 7 where I am creating LXC containers. An Ansible run in the Vagrant box. I create the container with Ansible like this:

```
- name: Create containers
  lxc_container:
    name: localdev_nginx
    container_log: true
    template: centos
    container_config:
      - 'lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.42.110/24'
      - 'lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 192.168.42.1'
    container_command: |
        yum -y install openssh-server
        echo "Som*th1ng" | passwd root --stdin
        ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ""
    state: started
```

This is create the container for me, but after this I can't access to the container from the Ansible. Just if I take the container ssh pubkey to the Vagrant known_hosts like this:

```
- name: Tell the host about our servers it might want to ssh to
  shell: ssh-keyscan -t rsa 192.168.42.110 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

And if I add the container root password in the Ansible hosts file like this:

```
[dev-webservers]
loc-dev-www1.internavenue.com hostname=loc-dev-www1.internavenue.com ansible_ssh_host=192.168.42.110  ansible_connection=ssh  ansible_user=root   ansible_ssh_pass=Som*th1ng
```

I hope it has a better solution, because really bad. How can I do it normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy the Vagrant box public key to the container's authorized_keys and in the hosts using this tag:

```
ansible_ssh_extra_args="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
```

This is only allowed from Ansible >2.0